# Get a part of string by N charecters to N charecters

Tags: c#

I want to get text from this long string. I need to take text after `dp%2F` until  `%2F`. How to do this in c#?

```
string foo = "Bubble-Free%2Fdp%2FB07W71K567%2Fref%3Dsr";
```

i want output like this: `B07W71K567`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're expected to attempt a solution on your own before asking. There are also several answered questions similar to yours that you can search for before posting your own question. Please visit [ask].

Comment: Do you know `string.IndexOf`?

Comment: You can use `IndexOf` to find where the first sting exists, then use it again with it's overload that takes an index to start searching from to find the second (since it's a sub-string of the first) and use those values to determine the start and length of the desired string and use `Substring` to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you want:

```
var result = Regex.Match(foo, @"dp%2F(.*)%2F").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Should be noted this will match up to the last "%2F" after the first "dp%2F" so the OP might want to use `(.*?)` instead.